Email field selectable in a User Lookup field?
I have a requirement of around 16 users that need to be selectable for a user lookup field that is used in an approval process but we don't have enough licenses for them...is there a way to select them within the user lookup field without them have a user account?? I've been playing around with an email field which is selectable in the user lookup field filter as a current user but I can't seem to get the lookup field to be able to select the email field....
Any ideas?? Thank you for your help in advance guys!

Approvers need to be users -- see Idea
